# get font size of rightBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I am going to use a custom font for a rightBarButtonItem, but I would like to get the current font size being used to set that size as the custom font size.

```
let myButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button",
                               style: .plain,
                               target: self,
                               action:#selector(MyVC.buttonTapped(_:)))

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myButton

let size = myButton...???

myButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "SomeCustomFont", size: size)! ], for: .normal)
```

Any idea? or another approach?

Answer (score -1):

You can get the size of `UIBarButtonItem` as follow :

```
 if let buttonItemView = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView{
        let buttonItemsize = buttonItemView.frame.size
        //your code
    }
```

Comment: how about the font size?

Comment: `UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.labelFontSize)` will return the standard font used for labels including UIBarButton item title label